# How to target es5 TypeScript in tsconfig and still have async / await use generators

Tags: typescript, async-await

I am targeting es5 in my tsconfig and so when I transpile with tsc I get the long (non generators) version of async / await.
So I figured if I added to my `tsconfig` the following:

```
 "lib": [
    "dom",
    "es5",
    "es2015.promise",
    "es2015.generator",
    "es2015.core",
    "es2015.collection",
    "es2015.iterable",
    "es2015.promise",
    "es2015.proxy",
    "es2015.reflect",
    "es2015.generator",
    "es2015.symbol",
    "es2015.symbol.wellknown" ]
```

TS will see that my browser supports generators and thus will take advantage of them, but still I get the longer format of async / await.

any ideas?

Thanks!!

Sean